# Regex for valid string between 1 and 150 separated by comma and hyphen

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I am trying to write a regex which takes string as input and can also include comma and an hyphen and validates for a valid number within 1 - 150 , arrived at the below regex, but it fails if i give the string as 1-151 , as it considers 51 in 151 as valid.

```
 1,10,1-150,25 valid
 0,1-10 invalid(as 0 is present)
 1,2,3-151,5 invalid (as 151 is present)
 10,0-4,5 invalid (as 0 is present)
```

The regex which I wrote

```
 ([1-9][,-])|([1-8][0-9][,-])|9[0-9][,-]|1[0-4][0-9][,-]|150[,-]
```

Comment: instead of a complex regex, can you just use split the string by the deliminators, then check each of the element in a loop? sometimes that can be more efficient on coding and also performance.

Comment: @some1 - planning to do same thing, if i dont find any simple solution for this in some time, just wanted to ask the people here.

Comment: Is `123-12-34-56` a *valid* string (no commas, hyphens only)?

Comment: Can you face negative number in your string?

Comment: @aloisdg - No, negative numbers should not be allowed, anything equal to or less than 0 is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex will do what you want:

```
^(([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-4][0-9]|150)([,-](?=\d)|$))+$
```

It looks for a set of valid numbers (1-9, 10-99, 100-149, 150) and checks that each number is followed by either `,`, `-`, or end of line (`$`). If the number is followed by a comma or hyphen it checks that the next character is a digit, so that it doesn't match (for example) `1,` or `34-`.

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/nNEkc8/9/)

Comment: works fine for all combinations except for numbers between 100 to 109

Comment: @G-- sorry I obviously fixed that just after you copied it... please try again...

Comment: @Rawling you are right, they are a hangover from the first version of the regex that I wrote.

Comment: @G-- thanks for accepting, I have made one slight modification since (a spurious `?` that got removed), please make sure you use that version. Demo link has been updated too. Sorry about the run-around!

Answer (score 1):

As @some1 said using `Split` with a bit of Linq is far easier to read (and later to change, improve, etc.). At least, here is this alternative:

```
private static bool IsValid(string s)
{
    return s.Split(new []{',','-'}).Select(int.Parse).All(x => x > 0 && x < 151);
}
```

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y7UhfS)

Following @Rawling and @Dmitry Bychenko proposition

```
private static bool IsValid(string s)
{
    return s.Split(new []{',','-'}).All(x => int.TryParse(x, out var v) && v >= 1 && v <= 150);
}
```

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5f3x9m)

Comment: `int.Parse` will throw an exception if the string is invalid.

Comment: @Rawling right OP may want to check for input if invalid string is possible. `int.TryParse` and `Contains` on delimiters

Comment: `.All(x => int.TryParse(x, out var v) && v >= 1 && v <= 150);`: each item must be a *valid integer* (`TryParse` returns `true`) and be in the `[1..150]` range; there's no need in `Select`

Comment: Side effect: since `Parse`/`TryParse` perform `Trim()`, the following string will be considered valid one: `"123     -       56   ,\t4"`: please, notice spaces and tabulation

Comment: Note that this breaks if you enter negative values (since it tries to parse an empty string on the left side of the minus sign).